# get specific row from all fetched

Tags: php, mysql

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC');
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $date = strtotime($row['date']);
    $dateb = date("d-M-H:i", $date);
    $items.= "<div class='item'" .
             "data-id=" . $row['id'] . "data-path='" . $row['cats'] . "'>" .
             "<span class='spandate'>" . $dateb . "</span>" . 
              "<span class='spantitle'>" . $row['title'] . "</span>" .
              "</div>\n";
}}
```

This gives me a serie of `item` named divs.
Now, is it possible on php side (and without writing a new SELECT statement, just using the above), to get a specific `item`, i.e. `item` with specific `id`?

Something like:

```
$x = 5;

$required_item = $items(where $row['id'] == x);
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = 5 ORDER BY date DESC`

Comment: @u_mulder, please read my post carefully.

Comment: I read it and this is all that I can say. Because selecting all values and fllter them in a php-loop is __overhead__.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your primary question is:

```
$x = 5;
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    if ($row['id'] == $x) {
        // do what you need - echo $row or add it to array.
    }
}
```

**But**, once again - selecting **all** values and filter them in a php-loop is **overhead**.

Suppose you have thousands of rows and you need to fetch and iterate over all of them in php. Mysql query will do it **much** faster:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = 5 ORDER BY date DESC');
while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    // do what you need  - echo $row or add it to array.
}
```

So, if you want to write proper code - use mysql filtering.